# TypeError: Object of type 'Category'(model) is not JSON serializable

Tags: javascript, json, django, python-3.x, serialization

Model class:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

The controller that works with model:

```
class AjaxLayoutView():

@login_required
def categories_ajax(request):
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    cats = serializers.serialize('json', categories)
    return HttpResponse(
        json.dumps(cats),
        content_type="application/json"
    )
```

TypeError: Object of type 'Category' is not JSON serializable
But in response in JavaScript with next code:

```
    $.getJSON( "/categories/ajax/", function( json ) {
    var src = JSON.parse(json);
    console.log(src);
    var valuesFromCategorys = [];

    for(var i=0;i<src.length;i++)
      valuesFromCategorys[i] = src[i].fields.name;
    console.log(src);

  $('#patient_category').editable({
    type: 'select',
    title: 'Оберіть нову категорію',
    source: valuesFromCategorys,
    ajaxOptions: { type:'POST'},
    params: function(params) {
      var objRequest = {category: params.value, pk:params.pk};
      console.log(params.value);
      return objRequest;
    },
    success: function(response, newValue) {
       console.log(response);
    }
  })
```

Comment: The error occurs on the `/patient_edit/ajax/` url. What `view` is handling this url?

Comment: yes, I just not correctly understood, I have some problems with english, I am trying to study it better)

Comment: error was here: "value = Category.objects.get(name=value)" and I was finding   it in wrong way all this time. Thank you very much) @nik_m

Comment: I have rolled back this question to the version that fits the answers. If you still have the problem with serialization, please do some research (READ: google the error message).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since your view is returning an array of objects, you can access any serialized value like this:

```
$.getJSON("/categories/ajax/", function(json) {
    var src = JSON.parse(json);
    for (var i = 0; i < src.length; i++) {
        var category = src[i];
        console.log(category.fields.<field_name>);
    }
});
```

Comment: yes, I did it. I get access to the fields with I'll work. But what means error that I wrote in the caption @nik_m

Comment: What do you get if above `HttpResponse` type: `print(json.dumps(cats))` ? Because I just tested locally and works pretty well!

Comment: yes, locally maybe it works, but in my code is error, and I can't find it

Answer (score 0):

Try to iterate over object and then make a list or dictionary .
then try json.dumps
we can not  dumps object directly.

```
@login_required
def categories_ajax(request):
categories = Category.objects.all()

cats= json.dumps([(dict(row.items())) for row in categories])
return HttpResponse(
    json.dumps(cats),
    content_type="application/json"
)
```

Comment: can you please give some example, I can try this:
categories_to_dict = model_to_dict(Category)
        cats = serializers.serialize('json', categories_to_dict)
        return HttpResponse(
            json.dumps(cats),
            content_type="application/json"
        )
But it doesn't work: AttributeError: type object 'Category' has no attribute 'id'